# Magento one-page checkout showing no payment method

Tags: magento

Am creating a module to add an additional payment system to Magento after creating the module. It is appearing in the admin panel and I have enabled it, but it is showing no payment method.

Answer (score 1):

So payment methods are shown on the checkout page after they pass the function `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods::_canUseMethod` now this function basically checks if the method itself is setup and if it is valid against the current quote via two calls.

1. The payment methods own function `canUseCheckout`. Now since you are creating your own method I dont know what you function here looks like but I guess it would not be too complex to debug by yourself.
2. The payment forms `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container::_canUseMethod`. Now what this function does is check the payment method against the country, currency and quote total.

With the following

```
return $method->isApplicableToQuote($this->getQuote(), Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY
    | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY
    | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX
);
```

Now if your payment method does not override anything here then it simply checks the config values of `min_order_total`, `max_order_total`, `specificcountry` and if you have any special currency checks.